# RoR + Paperclip - Have two objects reference same paperclip image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, url, reference, paperclip

I'm creating a demo portion to my website. Where each new demo account generates dummy data. The dummy data includes images. It takes way too long and takes up unnecessary space when creating these dummy images though. They are just copies of images that already exist in the database.

I have an `Image` object with the relationship `has_attached_file :pc_image`. I want a new image to reference the pc_image in an old image, not create a duplicate. I've been trying something like this (p statements added to show the difference), but it just won't work:

```
p old_image
=> images/001/original/old_image.jpg

new_image.pc_image = old_image.pc_image
new_image.save
p new_image
=> images/002/original/old_image.jpg
```

Notice the ID after images... 001 and 002. Paperclip seems to automatically create a new URL using the ID of its parent object instead of using the old URL. It doesn't duplicate the images though, which is what I want. But I'm getting a missing image in the view because the pc_image URL is pointing to an image that was never created instead of pointing to the old_image URL, which is what I want. Is this possible? Is there a good workaround?

Comment: You don't want to just use the `default_url` image?

Comment: @ptd - I'm not sure exactly what you mean (are you talking about the config?). But my current approach is to try and set the :url and :path of Image.pc_image depending on whether a static_reference is passed in build. I'm actually trying explicitly not to use the default_url.